# Parameter "self " unfilled

Tags: python, python-3.x

Начал изучать классы и столкнулся с такой проблемой. Кто понятно объяснить в чём ошибка чтобы на будущее запомнить)

```
class User:
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, age, country):
        self.first = first_name
        self.last = last_name
        self.age = age
        self. country = country
        self.login_attempts = 0

    def describe_user(self):
        user_info = {'First name': self.first.title(),
                     'Last name': self.last.title(),
                     'Age': self.age.title(),
                     'Country': self.country.title()
                     }
        print(user_info)

    def greet_user(self):
        print("Hello "+self.first.title(), self.last.title(), '!\n')

    def increment_login_attempts(self):
        self.login_attempts += 1
        print(self.login_attempts)

    def reset_login_attempts(self):
        self.login_attempts = 0
        print(self.login_attempts)


class Admin(User):
    def __init__(self,first_name, login_attempts):
        super().__init__(self, first_name, login_attempts)
        self.privileges = ['Разрешено удалять пользователей',
                           'Разрешено добавлять сообщения',
                           'Разрешено банить пользователей']

    def show_privileges(self):
        for privilege in self.privileges:
            print('Admin can: '+privilege)

hello_admin = Admin
hello_admin.show_privileges()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Когда вызывается метод у экземпляра класса, аргумент `self` подставляется автоматически (и его значение будет экземпляром класса). Когда вызывается у самого́ класса (а вы вызываете у класса), то никакого автоматического `self` нет и вам нужно его прописать самостоятельно — именно на это и намекает текст ошибки

Comment: Забыли скобки при создании объекта класса Admin: должно быть `hello_admin = Admin()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте:

```py
hello_admin = Admin()

hello_admin.show_privileges()
```

Насколько я понимаю, в случае, когда вы пишите `hello_admin = Admin`, вы дублируете класс в `hello_admin`, а когда пишите `hello_admin = Admin()` вы создаете объект класса `Admin`.